# Using variables inside of alignment attribute

Tags: pug

I am using pug 2.

I have created a `template.pug`, and within that template, it is broken down to `sub-a.pug` and `sub-b.pug`.  When they are on `sub-a.pug` the variable is defined as `- var alignment_text = "center";`. In `sub-b.pug` the variable is defined as `- var alignment_test = "center";`

On either `sub-a.pug` or `sub-b.pug`, there is a `content.pug` file.  On this file I try and use it like:

`<div align="#{alignment_text}"></div>`

When I try this it displays `#{alignment_text}` instead of `left` or `right`.

To resolve this I do:

```
if alignment_text = "center"
  <div align="center"</div>
else 
  <div align="center"</div>
```

Is there a way so that I can use the variables in quotes for alignment, id's or classes?

Comment: Note that the `align` attribute was superseded by CSS in 1996. There's really no reason to be using it this century.

Comment: @Quentin, I am using this for an email, so it's all tables.  but align works in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Pug documentation](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#attribute-interpolation), that syntax for attribute interpolation is old and no longer supported. The documentation provides an alternative syntax for current versions of Pug:

```
- var alignment_text = 'center'

// this is no longer supported
table(align='#{alignment_text}')

// use this syntax instead
table(align= alignment_text)
```